# How to replace only one character, and the last of the string

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

I need to make like a `str_replace()` but with only one character, and must be the last character of the string.

For example, if I have:

```
$var = "one,two,three,four,finish";
```

I need to be returned:

```
"one,two,three,fourfinish";
```

I need to replace the last `,` of the string.

I know it might be easy but I didn't find anything clear on the net!

Comment: You're not replacing - you're removing it. Is that what you actually want?

Comment: I want to remove it, I meant replace "," for ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`strrpos`](http://www.php.net/strrpos) to find the last occurrence of a string in a string, and then use [`substr`](http://www.php.net/substr):

```
<?php
    $var = "one,two,three,four,finish";

    if ($lastPosition = strrpos($var, ',')) {
        $var = substr($var, 0, $lastPosition) . substr($var, $lastPosition + 1);
    }

    var_dump($var); //string(24) "one,two,three,fourfinish"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/vWntDUtg)

---

If you want to *replace* it, you just have to concat the replacing string in your condition:

```
<?php
    $var = "one,two,three,four,finish";
    $replace = "-";

    if ($lastPosition = strrpos($var, ',')) {
        $var = substr($var, 0, $lastPosition) . $replace . substr($var, $lastPosition + 1);
    }

    var_dump($var); //string(24) "one,two,three,four-finish"
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Find the location of the last comma in the string using [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/strrpos) and remove it using [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/substr_replace):

```
echo substr_replace($var, '', strrpos($var, ','), 1);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/93401)

Comment: The character *must* exist though, or else it removes the first character: https://eval.in/93414

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Right - It's a good idea to make sure the character is indeed the one you want to remove (as you did in your answer) :)

Answer (score 0):

If the last word of $var always is "finish", you could use this:

```
$var = "one,two,three,four,finish";
$goodVar = str_replace(',finish', 'finish', $var);
print $goodVar;
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to remove the ',', I can't replace it with any word.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$string = 'one,two,three,four,finish';
$find = ',';
$replace = '';
$result = preg_replace(strrev("/$find/"),strrev($replace),strrev($string),1);
echo strrev($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "one,two,three,four,finish";

$var = preg_replace("/,([^,]*)$/", "\\1", $var);

// $var: "one,two,three,fourfinish"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strchr` to find the last occurence of a character in a given string

Try

```
$var = "one,two,three,four,finish";
$len =  strlen($var)-strlen(substr(strrchr($var,","),1));
echo  substr($var,0,$len-1).substr(strrchr($var,","),1);
```

Demo [here](https://eval.in/93407)

Answer (score 0):

You can find last offset for the char "," with strrpos. Then cut and merge.